# How to parse the list of urls and skip unneeded items (PHP)

Tags: php, parsing, text, text-files, output

I have a txt file with a lot of different urls. I want to parse the list and skip some urls to get final clean list. Please see part of the list below:

```
http://www.example.com/example1/
http://www.example.com/example2/
http://www.example.com/example3/
http://www.example.com/example4/
http://www.example.com/example.js
http://www.example.com/example.css
http://www.example.com/example1.js?v=123
http://www.example.com/{path}
http://www.example.com/feed/
http://www.example.com/?p=66
```

I want to skip all the urls like **.js** or **.css** or **{path}** or **/feed/** or **?p=66** and output everything into txt file again. I want to do that using PHP. Any advice ?

Comment: do you have a list of items that are unwanted? you can make an array of items and use string matching, since they are dissimilar ( file extensions and query params etc )

Comment: I need to create some matches: for example all the links with ?p= or all the links with .js?v= or {path}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

  $list = "http://www.example.com/example1/
http://www.example.com/example2/
http://www.example.com/example3/
http://www.example.com/example4/
http://www.example.com/example.js
http://www.example.com/example.css
http://www.example.com/example1.js?v=123
http://www.example.com/{path}
http://www.example.com/feed/
http://www.example.com/?p=66";

  $arr = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/",$list);

  // check our input array
  print_r($arr);

  $map = array();
  foreach($arr as $v){
    if(!preg_match("/({path}|\.(js|css)|\?p=\d+|\/feed\/)$/",$v)){
      $map[] = $v;
    }
  };

  // check our output array
  print_r($map);

?>
```

This assumes you want to match urls that don't end with `{path}` or `.css` or `.js` or `?p=##` (where # is a digit) or `/feed/`. This is why there is still the `/example1.js?v=123` being matched. To make it match anywhere in the string, rather than only at the end, remove the `$` from the end of the regular expression (just after the word `feed`).

### My console output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/example1/
    [1] => http://www.example.com/example2/
    [2] => http://www.example.com/example3/
    [3] => http://www.example.com/example4/
    [4] => http://www.example.com/example.js
    [5] => http://www.example.com/example.css
    [6] => http://www.example.com/example1.js?v=123
    [7] => http://www.example.com/{path}
    [8] => http://www.example.com/feed/
    [9] => http://www.example.com/?p=66
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/example1/
    [1] => http://www.example.com/example2/
    [2] => http://www.example.com/example3/
    [3] => http://www.example.com/example4/
    [4] => http://www.example.com/example1.js?v=123
)
```